# Sending a request from an android application to PHP and receiving a response

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpresponse

So I'm trying to send a request (with one parameter) from an android application to a PHP file which pulls data from a MySQL database and needs to return product information to the android app.

The android app has 3 activities. The Main activity just displays a button. On clicking this button, a new activity is launched which pulls data of the products (only make and model) from the back-end and displays it. On clicking one, I need to send a request to the back-end and pull data specific to the product that is selected. The product name is the primary key. The data is sent in JSON format between PHP and the android application.

Here's the code for the Android app that sends the request for just one specific product.

ViewProductActivity.class

```
public class ViewProductActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

TextView make;
TextView model;
TextView type;

private String url_get = "http://10.0.1.57/pull_product.php?";

String make_get;
private static final String TAG_MAKE = "Make";
private static final String TAG_MODEL = "Model";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "Type";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_product);

    make = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Make);
    model = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Model);
    type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Type);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    make_get = i.getStringExtra(TAG_MAKE);

    new GetProductDetails().execute();

}

class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Building Parameters

                List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("make", make_get));
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                url_get+=paramString;
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url_get);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                //ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                try {
                    response = client.execute(get);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                JSONObject test = null;
                try {
                    test = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Single Product Details", test.toString());
                try {
                    make.setText(test.getString(TAG_MAKE));
                    model.setText(test.getString(TAG_MODEL));
                    type.setText(test.getString(TAG_TYPE));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

I'm also pasting my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true" android:enabled="true">

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- All Products Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.AllProductsActivity"
        android:label="All Products" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.ViewProductActivity"
        android:label="View Product Details">
    </activity>

</application>

<!--  Internet Permissions -->


</manifest>
```

and the pull_product.php file

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","admin");
  mysql_select_db("test");

  $product=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["make"]);
  $query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE `Make` = '$product'";
  $q=mysql_query($query);
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($q);

        $product = array();
        $product["Make"] = $result["Make"];
        $product["Model"] = $result["Model"];
        $product["Type"] = $result["Type"];

  print(json_encode($product));
  mysql_close();
  ?>
```

And this is a sample of the table I'm trying to pull from

Make	Model	Type	Price	
Samsung	Galaxy S4	Mobile Phone	50000	
LG	Nexus 5	Mobile Phone	29000	
Apple	iPad 4	Tablet	40000

This is the error message that I'm getting in my LogCat:

```
05-14 18:05:19.001: D/AbsListView(19846): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-14 18:05:19.026: D/AbsListView(19846): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-14 18:05:19.031: E/ViewRootImpl(19846): sendUserActionProduct() mView == null
05-14 18:05:23.011: D/AbsListView(19846): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-14 18:05:23.021: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(19846): Parent view is not a TextView
05-14 18:05:23.086: D/ProgressBar(19846): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-14 18:05:23.086: D/ProgressBar(19846): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-14 18:05:23.086: D/ProgressBar(19846): updateDrawableBounds: right = 102
05-14 18:05:23.086: D/ProgressBar(19846): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 102
05-14 18:05:23.126: I/System.out(19846): main calls detatch()
05-14 18:05:23.126: D/AndroidRuntime(19846): Shutting down VM
05-14 18:05:23.126: W/dalvikvm(19846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418aec08)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846): Process: com.example.test, PID: 19846
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1179)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:644)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at com.example.test.ViewProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(ViewProductActivity.java:112)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-14 18:05:23.131: E/AndroidRuntime(19846):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 18:05:25.521: W/ApplicationPackageManager(20272): getCSCPackageItemText()

05-14 18:05:25.556: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(20272): Parent view is not a TextView
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? The URL is formed alright but the Request to the PHP file isn't going through.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Which of the exception handlers are being hit? What is the error message it contains?

Comment: You are performing network task on UI thread in doInBackground using runOnUiThread(), It may give networkInMainThreadException

Comment: Hey Hemant, that's the error message that I'm getting. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception remove calling `runOnUiThread()` method from `doInBackground(String... params)` method:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("make", make_get));
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    url_get+=paramString;
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url_get);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    //ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        response = client.execute(get);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject test = null;
    try {
        test = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("Single Product Details", test.toString());
    return test;
}
```

If you want to update your UI do it in `onPostExecute` method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject test) {
    // dismiss the dialog once got all details
    pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
            make.setText(test.getString(TAG_MAKE));
            model.setText(test.getString(TAG_MODEL));
            type.setText(test.getString(TAG_TYPE));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```